# Identifying sublists entirely contained within other lists

Tags: python, list

I would like to find the sublist within a list which matches another list, and from that create a new list:

So I would like this:

```
Lista = [["a", "b", "c"],["d", "e", "f"]]
Listb = ["b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

To generate this:

```
newvariable = ["d", "e", "f"]
```

because `a`, `b`, `c` is not contained in `listb`, but `d`, `e`, `f` is.

I have tried for loops with `all()` but can't seem to make them work?

Any ideas? I'm guessing this is something simple I'm missing.

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straight forward solution is

```
>>> Lista = [["a", "b", "c"],["d", "e", "f"]]
>>> Listb = ["b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
>>> set_b = set(Listb)
>>> 
>>> [l for l in Lista if all(x in set_b for x in l)]
[['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

which gives you a list with all the lists from `Lista` that are contained in `Listb`.

Note that instead of using `Listb` for the actual containment checks I am using the set `set_b` as sets have O(1) membership checks. (Otherwise, the above `all`-checks would have quadratic runtime.)

I assumed that the order of the elements in `Listb` does not matter. If it does, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [iterations.chain](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to flatten your array (or a copy) before comparing the elements.

Then you could cast your list into sets that have a minus operator.

**Second solution**
You could do something like that to recursively enumerate the list.
    def list_walk(iterable):
    if isinstance(iterable, List):
        for value in iterable:
            for subvalue in list_walk(iterable):
                yield subvalue
    else:
        yield iterable

Then use the same set trick as above.